# Multiplicity of Factors without Acutal Factoring

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there a way to get the multiplicity of all prime factors of a given composite number, without doing the actual factorisation?

For example $24$ would have multiplicities $(3,1)$, because of $24=2^33^1$.

Comment: I may be a bit confused about the actual question, but shouldn't this problem be at least as hard as deciding whether the given number is a prime? Indeed, if $m(p) = (k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n)$ where $k_i$ are multiplicities, then $p$ is a prime if and only if $m(p) = (1)$.

Comment: @WNY but this would oppose Gerry's answer because ["PRIMES is in P"](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%22Primes+is+in+P%22&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cse.iitk.ac.in%2Fusers%2Fmanindra%2Falgebra%2Fprimality_v6.pdf&ei=APlVT74FxJSzBvjq6e0G&usg=AFQjCNGvhedNI0NYO2ALeuGmJANPqp5WlQ) (link to the pdf)

Comment: @WNY, it certainly is at least as hard as deciding primality, but I think in fact it's much harder than that, and no easier than factorization (which is in practice, and one expects in theory, much harder than deciding primality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is believed that even deciding whether an integer is squarefree is as hard as factoring.

Comment: Solvable in linear time on a quantum computer, you mean?

Comment: When I have a quantum computer on my desk, I'll worry about how hard it is to solve problems on a quantum computer. In the meantime, that's not the computation model I have in mind.

Comment: Could reply to @WNY 's [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117034/multiplicity-of-factors-without-acutal-factoring#comment271987_117034)?

Comment: The references cited in http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=379888&tstart=0 may be useful. There's also a reference at http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=379871&tstart=0.